# Split list into two columns. List doesn't have blocks but need to split on closest <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to break a list like the one below into two columns but to only break before the closest `<p>` tag. I cannot use css3 because you can only tell it to not break within an element. I do not have the element to define that. NOTE: I cannot add html to this list.

https://jsfiddle.net/j9b3wuuw/

```
<p>A</p>
<span>Asdf</span>
<span>Axxxx</span>
<p>B</p>
<span>Basdf</span>
<span>Basdf</span>
<span>Basdf</span>
<span>Basdf</span>
<span>Basdf</span>
<p>C</p>
<span>Casdf</span>
<span>Casdf</span>
<span>Casdf</span>
```

Expected result

```
A        C
Asdf    Casdf
Axxxx   Casdf
B       Casdf
Basdf
Basdf
Basdf
Basdf
Basdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been using jQuery but plain vanilla javascript. There's probably a shorter way using jQuery.

What the code below does: first, a second `<div>` is inserted. Next, all `<p>` elements are retrieved and the last item stored in `last` variable. The while loop gets all siblings (`<span>` elements) one at a time and moves them to the second `<div>`. Finally, the last `<p>` is also moved there as first child.

```js
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="second"></div>';
var div2 = document.getElementById("second");
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
var last = list[list.length - 1];
while (sib = last.nextSibling) {
  div2.appendChild(sib);
}
div2.insertBefore(last, div2.childNodes[0]);
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 options">
  <p class="letter-header" id="A">A</p>
  <span>Aaasdfasdf</span>
  <span>Asdfasdf</span>
  <span>Aba</span>
  <span>Accc</span>
  <span>Azzd</span>
  <p class="letter-header" id="B">B</p>
  <span>Baasdfasdf</span>
  <span>Bsdfasdf</span>
  <span>Bba</span>
  <span>Bccc</span>
  <span>Bzzd</span>
  <p class="letter-header" id="F">F</p>
  <span>Faasdfasdf</span>
  <span>Fsdfasdf</span>
  <span>Fba</span>
  <span>Fccc</span>
  <span>Fzzd</span>
  <span>Fba</span>
  <span>Fccc</span>
  <span>Fzzd</span>
  <span>Fba</span>
  <span>Fccc</span>
  <span>Fzzd</span>
  <p class="letter-header" id="W">W</p>
  <span>Waasdfasdf</span>
  <span>Wsdfasdf</span>
  <span>Wba</span>
  <span>Wccc</span>
  <span>Wzzd</span>
  <p class="letter-header" id="Z">Z</p>
  <span>Zaasdfasdf</span>
  <span>Zsdfasdf</span>
  <span>Zba</span>
  <span>Zccc</span>
  <span>Zzzd</span>
</div>
```

[DEMO (Fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/j9b3wuuw/2/) to just split the last section.

To split the list in two more or less equally sized lists, the position of the `<p>` closest to but after the middle of the complete list needs to be find first, see the [second demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j9b3wuuw/5/) to achieve that.

Comment: So this is very close. My example was definitely too simple. I wanted to go to half way down the complete list, the find the next P tag and do the split there, not the last p tag. Also just to be clear, this shouldn't the the middle P tag, but rather the closest P tag to the middle of the complete list.

Comment: Updated my answer and added another demo for that case: https://jsfiddle.net/j9b3wuuw/5/

Comment: Awesome looks great! Is it possible to somehow just insert </div><div>. That's preferred but if its not possible, creating a duplicate div around the first column?

Comment: Depends on your actual structure, you can add anything you want as long as you are able to address it later on again. You don't even need to add any element if there is already an element you want to move the content to.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking for a Jquery solution but according to your fiddle, you are using bootstrap? if so, can't you just wrap each group with a div in html?

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p class="letter-header" id="A">A</p>
      <span>Aaasdfasdf</span>
      <span>Asdfasdf</span>
      <span>Aba</span>
      <span>Accc</span>
      <span>Azzd</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I cannot add html, otherwise I would have done that to use the css3 option.